# Monitor Asus VS247H doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I've bought a new monitor Asus VS274H and tried to connect it via HDMI in Ubuntu, but it doesnt work without mirroring screens. Mirroring is default and it works right, but when I try to extend desktop and give the new monitor any higher resolution than 1024x600, the error message appears: `"requested position/size for CRTC 147 is outside the allowed limit: position=(1360, 0), size=(1920, 1080), maximum=(2960, 2960)"`

The same problem appeared with my old monitor, but it was an old one so 1024x600 was quite enough for me back then. Any ideas how to fix the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a new resolution that holds the 1360 + 1920 pixels. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions
for a guide to this.